# Swift - Firebase Auth Provider Microsoft problem redirect about:blank

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, azure-active-directory

Here is my problem, I tried to get the Firebase documentation to add the Microsoft provider to my iOS application (13.2), so I get to the authentication then after passing it at the time of redirection, it shows me a blank page with about:blank and doesn’t go back to the application to retrieve the credentials...

```
var provider = OAuthProvider(providerID: "microsoft.com")

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    provider.customParameters = [
        "prompt": "consent",
        "tenant": "my TenantId is here"
    ]
}

provider.getCredentialWith(nil) { credential, error in
        if error != nil {
            print("ERROR ? \(error)")
            // Handle error.
        }
        print("Crediential \(credential)")
        if credential != nil {
            Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential!) { authResult, error in
                if error != nil {
                    // Handle error.
                }
                Auth.auth().currentUser!.link(with: credential!) { authResult, error in
                    if error != nil {
                        // Handle error.
                    }
                    // Microsoft credential is linked to the current user.
                    // IdP data available in authResult.additionalUserInfo.profile.
                    // OAuth access token can also be retrieved:
                    // authResult.credential.accessToken
                    // OAuth ID token can also be retrieved:
                    // authResult.credential.idToken
                }
                // User is signed in.
                // IdP data available in authResult.additionalUserInfo.profile.
                // OAuth access token can also be retrieved:
                // authResult.credential.accessToken
                // OAuth ID token can also be retrieved:
                // authResult.credential.idToken
            }
        }
    }
```

Active directory config:

[image: Active directory config]

Here's how it works:

*.firebaseapp.com -> login.micosoftonline.com (select account) -> (if not logged) login.live.com -> login.microsoftonline.com (accept permissions) -> *.firebaseapp.com -> about:blank

I tried to work around this problem by other means but without success by retrieving an accesToken via MSAL.

Comment: I think you have to handle the closure of the LoginView once you’ve received the credential. You may be able to do this using what is said on step 5 on this page: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/microsoft-oauth#before_you_begin